# VBA: Arthimetic overflow converting int to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, insert-into

I am trying to insert data into a temp database in SQL Server 2012.

This is my data, and the datatype used:

```
1234ab  nchar(25) NOT NULL primary key
240     smallint
4535ab  nchar(10)
04/01/2013  date
58f658      nchar(6)
584g6555    nchar(9)
Insufficient Data   text
10      tinyint
N/A     nchar(5)
N/A     nchar(5)
4       smallint
N/A     nchar(5)
N/A     nchar(5)
4       smallint
N/A     nchar(5)
N/A     nchar(5)
4       smallint
51651.00    numeric(10,7)
65465.50    numeric(14,10)
65465.00    numeric(10,7)
4845.00     numeric(14,10)
04/01/2013  date
5465.00     numeric(18,3)
5465.00     numeric(18,3)
5546.00     numeric(10,7)
test.html   text
note test   text
```

All non-numeric data has the appropriate " ' " around them when importing.
(BTW some datatypes seem bigger than needed, but this is just a small data sample to test the import)
But I am getting the following error:

> Arthimetic overflow converting int to data type numeric

I am just using a regular `INSERT INTO` statement.
I have been staring at my screen for quite a bit now, so I might just read over it.. but what am I missing here? The data doesn't seem to be bigger than the domains.

BTW if you need more information please let me know.

Comment: You may want to post your `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 51651.00    numeric(10,7)

The "numeric(10, 7)" means 10 digits altogether, with 7 of them to the right of the decimal point. That doesn't leave enough room to the *left* of the decimal for "51651".

A different dbms might give you a more informative error message. This one is from PostgreSQL.

```
ERROR:   numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 10, scale 7 must round 
         to an absolute value less than 10^3.
```

Comment: I thought it worked like this (10,7) = 10 total number and 7 number to the right, IF used. So 12,1234567 or 1234567,12 will both work.. But your saying (10,7) will only allow 3 to the left of the decimal?

Comment: It's not hard to test. `create table wibble (n numeric(10,7)); insert into wibble values (12345.67);`